# How can I adjust the y-axis labels in my plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data and code:

```
# Load libraries and data.

library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
    Product = c(755, 728, 417, 355, 913, 634, 385, 208, 204, 696, 968, 816, 279, 869, 823, 646, 986, 674, 806, 335, 731, 734, 107, 105, 512, 859, 159, 113, 353, 105, 205, 919, 243, 717, 838, 408, 423, 357, 408, 464, 724, 643, 943, 648, 623, 451, 449, 135, 842, 711),
    Category = c("Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese"),
    Sub_Category = c("White", "Camembert", "White", "Camembert", "White", "Brie", "Brown", "Wholemeal", "White", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Gouda", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "Brown", "White", "Wholemeal", "Gouda", "Gouda", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "White", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Brown", "Brie", "Brie", "White", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "Gouda", "White", "Wholemeal", "Brown", "White", "Camembert", "Brie", "Brie", "Camembert", "Brie", "Camembert", "Gouda", "Camembert", "Wholemeal", "White", "Camembert"),
    Fibre = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)

# Organise data for plotting.

proportions <- df %>%
  group_by(Category, Sub_Category) %>%
  summarise(Proportion = mean(Fibre == TRUE) * 100, .groups = 'drop')

# Plot data.

ggplot(data = proportions, 
       aes(x = Proportion, 
           y = interaction(Sub_Category, Category), 
           fill = Category)
       ) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) + 
  labs(fill = "Category")
```

Which produces output:

[image: Plot]

The y axis labels include the Category and Sub_Category data (e.g. Brown AND Bread). I would like them to include only the Sub_Category data (i.e. just Brown or White or Wholemeal, etc, with the category data given by the legend).

**How can I adjust the y-axis labels to remove the category information and keep the sub-category information?**

Ideally, the solution would be programmatic (rather than manually editing y-labels) as my real data has many more categories and sub-categories than this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the interaction in the plot code, create it in the data prep code and manually edit the results. Below I create a new, auxiliary variable `yaxis` in order to make this more clear. This forces me to also edit the y axis label.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(tidyverse)
)

# Load libraries and data.

df <- data.frame(
  Product = c(755, 728, 417, 355, 913, 634, 385, 208, 204, 696, 968, 816, 279, 869, 823, 646, 986, 674, 806, 335, 731, 734, 107, 105, 512, 859, 159, 113, 353, 105, 205, 919, 243, 717, 838, 408, 423, 357, 408, 464, 724, 643, 943, 648, 623, 451, 449, 135, 842, 711),
  Category = c("Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Cheese", "Bread", "Bread", "Cheese"),
  Sub_Category = c("White", "Camembert", "White", "Camembert", "White", "Brie", "Brown", "Wholemeal", "White", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Gouda", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "Brown", "White", "Wholemeal", "Gouda", "Gouda", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "White", "Brie", "Wholemeal", "Wholemeal", "Brown", "Brie", "Brie", "White", "Wholemeal", "Camembert", "Gouda", "White", "Wholemeal", "Brown", "White", "Camembert", "Brie", "Brie", "Camembert", "Brie", "Camembert", "Gouda", "Camembert", "Wholemeal", "White", "Camembert"),
  Fibre = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
)

# Organise data for plotting.

proportions <- df %>%
  group_by(Category, Sub_Category) %>%
  summarise(Proportion = mean(Fibre == TRUE) * 100, .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(yaxis = interaction(Sub_Category, Category),
         yaxis = sub("\\..*$", "", yaxis),
         yaxis = factor(yaxis, levels = yaxis))

# Plot data.

ggplot(data = proportions, 
       aes(x = Proportion, 
           y = yaxis, 
           fill = Category)
) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) + 
  labs(y = "Sub Category", fill = "Category")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-20 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>